# Two connection pools are unintentionally created in a Spring Boot + Hibernate environment

Tags: spring, hibernate, hikaricp

I am developing a system with Spring + Hibernate.

I am creating a Hibernate SessionFactory with the following source code.

```
private SessionFactory buildSessionFactory(String profileName) {
　try {
　　ResourceBundle resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("application-" + profileName);

　　// Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
　　Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

　　configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class",
　　　　resourceBundle.getString("spring.datasource.driver-class-name"));

　　configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", resourceBundle.getString("spring.datasource.url"));

　　configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username",
　　　　resourceBundle.getString("spring.datasource.username"));

　　configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password",
　　　　resourceBundle.getString("spring.datasource.password"));

　　SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();

　　return sessionFactory;
　}
}
```

When I ran this, I got the following warning.

```
2023-10-03T18:35:06.861+09:00 WARN 23412 — [ main] org.hibernate.orm.connections.pooling : HHH10001002: Using built-in connection pool (not intended for production use)
```

To resolve this warning, I added the following setting to the buildSessionFactory method.

```
configuration.setProperty(“hibernate.connection.provider_class”,“org.hibernate.hikaricp.internal.HikariCPConnectionProvider”);
```

The following is the log after making the above modifications.

```
2023-10-03T18:46:33.400+09:00  INFO 3480 --- [           main] c.m.e.d.DiscountAmountApplication        : The following 1 profile is active: "local"
2023-10-03T18:46:34.095+09:00  INFO 3480 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-10-03T18:46:34.129+09:00  INFO 3480 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 18 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-10-03T18:46:34.505+09:00  INFO 3480 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-10-03T18:46:35.042+09:00  INFO 3480 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@6ada9c0c
2023-10-03T18:46:35.044+09:00  INFO 3480 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.

(omission)

2023-10-03T18:46:40.453+09:00  INFO 3480 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.c.i.ConnectionProviderInitiator  : HHH000130: Instantiating explicit connection provider: org.hibernate.hikaricp.internal.HikariCPConnectionProvider
2023-10-03T18:46:40.458+09:00  INFO 3480 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-2 - Starting...
2023-10-03T18:46:40.533+09:00  INFO 3480 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-2 - Added connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@41bb5a40
2023-10-03T18:46:40.533+09:00  INFO 3480 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-2 - Start completed.
2023-10-03T18:46:40.712+09:00  INFO 3480 --- [           main] o.h.b.i.BytecodeProviderInitiator        : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : bytebuddy
```

Two connection pools are created unintentionally.

I want to use the connection pool generated by Spring Boot because it is a waste of resources, but I could not find a way to do so.

I have mapping information in my hibernate.cfg.xml, and I don't want to make significant changes to the current session factory creation method.

Is there a way to solve the connection pool issue?

Comment: Ditch the way you configure hibenate in the Spring Boot application, and just use the `EntityManager` and JPA. If you want a hibernate session use `entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);` but with the current state of JPA you rarely need this.